# create new shapefile in arcmap using python

Tags: python, gis, arcmap

I am trying to add a shape file in arc map without having  the longitude and latitude but did not work . so how can i add new empty shape file in arcmap by using a simple python script  ?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Share what you have tried thus far.  Since your problem is with code you have tried, share the related code.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a new shapefile, you can use [arcpy.CreateFeatureClass_management](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-feature-class.htm). For example, if you want a new point data shapefile, you'd use something like

```
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r'C:\output', "points.shp", "POINT")
```

Comment: Then use AddField (or AddFields) as necessary. See documentation - it is one of the more straight forward methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if you are reading a text file with point coordinates. First step to creat feature class:arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outputpath,fc,"Polygon").And create a insert cursor:cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,["shape@"]). Then obtain the points from text file and add them to an array to creat a polygon:

```
line_array = acrpy.Array()    
point = arcpy.Point()
for line in fileinput.input(infile):
    point.ID, point.X, point.Y = line.split()
    line_array.add(point)
polygon = arcpy.Polygon(line_array)
cursor.insertRow([polygon])
fileinput.close()
del cursor
```