# How do I publish a FeatureLayer using ArcGIS for python?

Tags: python, gis, publish, arcgis

I want to publish a feature layer using arcgis for python. As a first step I want to create a shapefile according to the documentation (https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.gis.toc.html?highlight=import_data#arcgis.gis.ContentManager.import_data):

```
import os
import json
from IPython.display import display
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geometry import Point, Geometry
from arcgis.features import SpatialDataFrame

# Create an anonymous connection to ArcGIS Online
gis = GIS()

# create geometry ========================================================
geo = [Point({"x" : -118.15, "y" : 33.80, "spatialReference" : {"wkid" : 4326}})]

# create spatialdataframe ========================================================
df = SpatialDataFrame(geometry=geo);

# create feature layer from spatialdatafrme ============================
featureLayer = gis.content.import_data(df)
```

Now the problem with running this code is that it produces the following error:

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py in record(self, *recordList, **recordDict)
   1067         fieldCount = len(self.fields)
   1068         # Compensate for deletion flag
-> 1069         if self.fields[0][0].startswith("Deletion"): fieldCount -= 1
   1070         if recordList:
   1071             record = [recordList[i] for i in range(fieldCount)]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

After digging into the code I feel like this is a bug. However, my question is: How do I publish a featurelayer from scratch using arcgis for python? I understand that there are solutions for using `arcpy` (e.g. [create new shapefile in arcmap using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752064/create-new-shapefile-in-arcmap-using-python)) but as far as I understand arcpy is going to be replaced by arcgis for python at some point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/updating-features-in-a-feature-layer/)

You can upload your list of points to AGOL then use .publish() to feature layer